# Finding all permutations in a list of numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

Currently I have an array of 13 values and I want to find all the permutations of it and exclude the ones that summations that exceed a given threshold.  The problem is that there are so many values it never finishes. Is there a way to optimize what I have?

```
 public class formPermut
        {
            public void swapTwoNumber(ref int a, ref int b)
            {
                int temp = a;
                a = b;
                b = temp;
            }
            public void prnPermut(int[] list, int k, int m)
            {
                int i;
                if (k == m)
                {
                    for (i = 0; i <= m; i++)
                        Console.Write("{0}", list[i]);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                else
                    for (i = k; i <= m; i++)
                    {
                        swapTwoNumber(ref list[k], ref list[i]);
                        prnPermut(list, k + 1, m);
                        swapTwoNumber(ref list[k], ref list[i]);
                    }
            }
        }
        public static void RecExercise11()
        {
            int n, i;
            formPermut test = new formPermut();
            int[] arr1 = new int[13];

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n Recursion : Generate all possible permutations of an array :");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");

            Console.Write(" Input the number of elements to store in the array [maximum 13 digits ] :");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write(" Input {0} number of elements in the array :\n", n);
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" element - {0} : ", i);
                arr1[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.Write("\n The Permutations with a combination of {0} digits are : \n", n);
            test.prnPermut(arr1, 0, n - 1);
            Console.Write("\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question a professor gave? If so, did he give parameters that the program should be capable of handling? Its possible that the problem is just too big for that many parameters. I can't tell if its the algorithm that is slow or just that the problem is too big because its not obvious what the code is doing.

Comment: First thing is first - rename all your variables. Give them meaningful names. You'll thank me a year or so in the future, when you are 6 months into your first job as a programmer and have to do some maintenance work on an old code you wrote.

Comment: The code finds all the permutations for a given sets of numbers you input.  The only parameters is a list of integers and a ceiling that the summation of that particular summation can't exceed, if it does, it doesn't need to be included.

Comment: Shouldn't it be maximum 5 elements?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I updated those numbers

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem.  See http://xyproblem.info/ for what that is. 
 That said, what does "the summation of that particular summation" mean?  It doesn't matter what order you put an array into, its sum should always be the same.

Comment: I mean when you add array[i] + array[i+1] + array[i+2]....if the sum is > the limit. that combination is removed.

Comment: You still aren't at all clear - what is `i`? As mentioned, order doesn't matter for summation. Where in your code are you testing the summation?

Comment: i worded it wrong. I'll fix it.  When I input 13 numbers to into the program, there are a lot of combination/permutations.  The applications never finishes in a timely manner.  Is there a way to optimize what I have?

Comment: The sum of an array is invariant under permutations. You have not precisely or accurately stated what problem you're really trying to solve here. Clarify the problem.

Comment: @EricLippert Is there anyway to make it not take forever to finish the list when I use an array with 13 indexes.

Comment: Are you actually trying to solve a variation on the subset-sum problem? **That problem is not concerned with permutations; it is concerned with subsets**.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm trying to make sure that my current implementation isn't extremely inefficient. Right now, there are a lot of returned results and it takes forever for the it to finish(longer than anyone would want to wait).  Is this going to happen regardless of the implementation(because of the set size) or is there maybe another approach that isn't so time heavy?

Comment: No one can answer your question because you haven't explained your problem at all. For example, combinations and permutations are not the same thing, and if you don't know that, perhaps you need to understand your problem so you can explain it to others.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you need to exclude the permutations whose sum is greater than a threshold is a perfect candidate for backtracking (don't search this term yet), think about a way to speed this up (there's n! permutations so it won't finish in a while).

Imagine this like a tree were the leaves are the permutations themselves and answer:

- Do you need to know the full permutation before being able to exclude it?
- What calculations can you make in a non-leaf node?

Comment: That's one problem. The first issue I want to tackle, is handling the list of permutations. Is there anyway to make it not take forever to finish the list when I use an array with 13 indexes.

Comment: If your algorithm is correct it won't matter if you're able to finish it quickly enough because then you can be asked to run against an array of 14 digits and you'll try to optimize it, and there's no way to optimize it beyond `Omega(n!)` (assuming your print function somehow takes constant time, which clearly wont) because there exists `n!` permutations, so you shouldn't be trying to print all permutations (unless the whole array is less than the sum). In fact I think that your problem isn't correctly stated: If the sum of the array is less than a number you should not print any permutation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at using the Permutation library from here

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G

and then write your filtering on top of that.